# SVG and viewBox values

Tags: inkscape, svg, xml

I'm just curious if anybody knows how `viewBox` values (i.e. `viewBox="a b c d"`) are determined.

I'm trying to understand Inkscape's SVG functionality, so what I've done is created a document in Inkscape that is `100px` x `100px`, drawn a line from the left side of the viewport (i.e. `0` horizontal value) to the right side (i.e. `100` horizontal value).

Strangely, however, when I save this document as a Plain SVG file, and then open the file in a text editor, the `viewBox` values are set to `viewBox="0 0 26.458333 26.458334"` instead of, say, `viewBox="0 0 100 100"`.

Does anybody know how these values (`0 0 26.458333 26.458334`) are determined, and why there is seemingly no relation between them and the viewport dimensions?

P.S. I know you can edit the `viewBox` property manually in the document options, but I'm still curious as to why Inkscape sets them to funky values.

Comment: thank you for this question and the way you asked it. It is exactly what I was wondering, down to the P.S. at the bottom.

Comment: @Corey glad it helped more than just me

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Inkscape uses mm as the default *display-unit* or [*user-unit*](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Units_In_Inkscape#Example) for your document. *User-units* are used to store values in the SVG file.

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 26.458333 26.458333">
```

This tag describes a drawing size of `100px x 100px`. The viewBox attribute defines that `100px x 100px` is equivalent to `26.458333 x 26.458333 user units`.

The SVG scale factor would be `1px / 0.2645 user-unit`, which can be used by a SVG renderer to convert all the values that are stored in *user-units* to the *real-world* drawing dimensions.

---

In this case Inkscape wants to store the values in `mm`, so it has to know how `px` relates to `mm`. The [CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) describes that absolute length units are fixed in relation to each other: `96px = 1in`

This means `100px = 1.041666667in = 2.645833333cm = 26.45833333mm`

So that's where the `26.45833333` comes from.

---

If you want Inkscape to store all your values in `px`, you can change the default *Display units* or *user-units* to `px` in the document properties (File > Document Properties > Tab: Page > General > Display Units)

1. Default, mm:

[image: Document properties mm]

2. Changed: px:

[image: Document properties px]

Exporting the same document will result in the following SVG tag:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
```

Now the SVG scale factor is `1px / 1 user-unit`.

If you want to know more about this subject, there is a more detailed explanation in the [Inkscape Wiki](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Units_In_Inkscape#Example)

Remarks:

- Inkscape v0.92 uses a relation of `96px/in`, Inkscape v0.91 and earlier used a value of `90px/in`

Comment: Wow. Very interesting. So there was a rhyme and reason to it. Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: I'm going to remember the whiteout technique you used.  I normally put red squares around the important parts of screenshots, yours is **so** much nicer.